# Fetch method put give "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: javascript, json, django, fetch

I state that the script works: successfully changes the correct field to the correct value. Despite this I get this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".

This is the client-side js code. The function gets ad 'id' , the field to change and the value :

```
function mark(id,field,yesno){
  fetch('/emails/'+id,{
    method : 'PUT',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body : JSON.stringify({
      [field]:yesno
    })
  })
  .then(response =>response.json())
  .catch(error => {console.log('Error while processing the request:' , error)})
}
```

The piece of code on the views.py

```
...
 elif request.method == "PUT":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        if data.get("read") is not None:
            email.read = data["read"]
        if data.get("archived") is not None:
            email.archived = data["archived"]
        email.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
...
```

And the models.py

```
class Email(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="emails")
    sender = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="emails_sent")
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="emails_received")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "sender": self.sender.email,
            "recipients": [user.email for user in self.recipients.all()],
            "subject": self.subject,
            "body": self.body,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
            "read": self.read,
            "archived": self.archived
        }
```

Comment: Your server does not appear to return any data but yet you call `response.json()`.

Comment: Yes, return nothing. But if I delete .`then(response =>response.json())` I receive : 'Fetch failed loading: PUT'